# Python selenium webscraping with google translate extension

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape multiple web pages across the world. So, I want to translate the website using Google translate extension and then scrape the page using selenium.

I did some research and figured out how to add extension while running selenium.

1. [download google translate extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb?hl=en)
2. [Create .crx file](http://www.helloselenium.com/2014/09/how-to-create-crx-file-from-already.html)
3. [add extension to selenium](http://www.helloselenium.com/2014/09/how-to-add-extension-to-google-chrome.html)

but I have no idea how to automatically execute the extension (By default, it does nothing)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_extension('./translate.crx')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "./chromedriver", chrome_options = option)
driver.get("naver.com")
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body")))

''' @@@@ Here I want something like@@@@
driver.execute_extension("translate this page")
'''

print driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").text
driver.quit()
```

Also, I found that the extension doesn't translate the original HTML, so I might have to use a different method for crawling. (Maybe passing ctrl-a, ctrl-c, ctrl-v instead by_tag_name("body"))

Could you give me any pointer for this?

Comment: I found that translate to English after scraping would be better. Try use [googletrans library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/googletrans) if you have similar issue.

Comment: Consegui traduzir com a lib https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/